# How to get the name of files inside a local folder using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, file

I am trying to get the name of files inside a folder and store it in a javascript array.

Example:
I want to store the file's name as an array but the elements in an array should be the name of files present in the local directory.

Comment: what research have you done, what did you find out? This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624450/how-to-get-the-contents-of-the-directory-from-local-pc-in-javascript

Comment: Are you using Nodejs? If so, please have a look of this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727191/14032355